# How can I push Unity games into my Android Studio app?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I am building an app that can host multiple games. The games will be made in Unity3D. For the app, I was torn between Unity3D and Android Studio. I am thinking of using Android Studio.

Can the desired task be done in Android Studio? Later on I also want to be able to load new games into the app from a Web Server, that's why I'm going with Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to export from Unity into an Android library, you can only have one instance of the UnityPlayer at a time. And it is not possible to restart that instance once you quit it. But I never tried to have multiple Unity projects in one Android Project, so it might still be kind of possible

Unity introduced [native library support in 2019.3](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/06/17/add-features-powered-by-unity-to-native-mobile-apps/) (still in beta). Perhaps this will develop in your favour, but your requirements are a bit exotic.

Another approach could be to develop all games in one Unity-Project and then export scenes of a single game as AssetBundles. That would eliminate the need to handle multiple Unity-Projects but has downsides on his own.